# How to render HTML comment tag in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, html-email

I am writting some html for emails using django, and I want to use the `<!--[if !mso]><!-->` (required for conditional rendering for outlook desktop client)

The problem is when I print the html_content obtained after django `render_to_string()`, the HTML comment tag is missing.

I tried to put my html comment inside a `{%autoescape off%}{%endautoescape%}` but for some reason it does not work.

Anyone having an idea on how to how to achieve my goal here?

Thanks

Comment: Django does not do anything to HTML comments in the template though. Are they present in a Django comment / in some if-else condition? Or is the comment in some variable?

Comment: Maybe just try without the extra `<!-->`, i.e. `<!--[if !mso]>...<![endif]-->`

Comment: The tag is not in any if-else, to reproduce just pass a template containing the tag to render_to_string() and print the result.
I tried to play with the comment syntax to make it work, but it's not working. I am using django 2.2